# QAbstractItemModel and QTreeView

Tags: c++, qt, qtreeview, qabstractitemmodel

I need working examples (c++) of show own data model in QtreeView.

Comment: That's too vague for Stack Overflow : you should try Google to get you started and come ask questions when you encounter more specific problems.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There's a pretty good QTreeView/QAbstractItemModel example [here](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtwidgets-itemviews-simpletreemodel-example.html). It's fairly straightforward once you get used to QT's ultra-generic model... just don't expect it to be as simple or obvious as Java's TreeModel.

Comment: what I find quite bad about the linked article is that it mainly describes how their example works, and only in between a bit about how the QTreeView uses that model. in addition, it isn't explained under which circumstances one should even write an own model, when there is a quite potent one available already (QStandardItemModel). Not related to that article but to this answer: answers should contain the main gist of linked article (in case of a website going offline), that's missing here...

Comment: Qt's treeview works like a sh*t since it forces you to create a real tree for the underlying data when you use `QAbstractitemModel` (if you don't, you will soon lost in the `index()/parent()` methods), which in effect provides no separation of view/model at all.